# Exoplayer pause button does not appear initially

Tags: android, exoplayer

So exoplayer all setup, working fineish. I am playing a m3u8 video. No issues there. But when I hit play, the play button is not replaced with a pause button. It just disappears but the pause buttons appears when I go into fullscreen. Odd no?

Btw this is within a react native component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of some rendering issue when you embed Android Native View in react-native. Using Layout inspector in Android studio I found that the button size is 0. So remeasuring and calling layout on the view whenever player state changes should solve the issue.

Have a method to remeasure and layout like below:

```
private fun reLayout(controlView: View?, controlViewsParent: View?) {
    controlView?.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(controlViewsParent.measuredWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(controlViewsParent.measuredHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))
    controlView?.layout(view.left, view.top, view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight)
}
```

Add `Player.EventListener` to the exoplayer Instance. 
This listener should give you below overridden methods in which you call the `relayout()`. These two overridden methods are called whenever ExoPlayer state changes and when you pause and play. So remeasuring and rendering the view fixes the button issue.

```
override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
    relayout(controlView, controlViewsParent)
}

override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
    relayout(controlView, controlViewsParent)
}
```

My pause and play buttons are inside a FrameLayout like:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/exo_play_pause_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here my `controlView` is `exo_play_pause_container` and `controlViewsParent` is root of this layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but this is my solution based on Ankshay Bhat response:

VideoPlayer.java

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player.EventListener;

public class VideoPlayer extends PlayerView {

    private SimpleExoPlayer player;

    @Override
    public SimpleExoPlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setFile(String url) {
        preparePlayer(url);
    }

    public VideoPlayer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
        this.setPlayer(player);
    }

    private void preparePlayer(String url) {
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url);
        // Set the media item to be played.
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        // Prepare the player.
        player.prepare();
    }

    public void addOnAttachStateChangeListener(EventListener listener) {
        this.player.addListener(listener);
    }
}
```

VideoPlayerView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player.EventListener;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class VideoPlayerView extends FrameLayout {
    private Context context;
    public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

    public VideoPlayerView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.init();
    }

    private void init(){
        videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer(context);
        videoPlayer.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int state) {
                post(measureAndLayout);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIsPlayingChanged(boolean isPlaying) {
                post(measureAndLayout);
            }
        });
        this.addView(videoPlayer);
    }

    private final Runnable measureAndLayout = () -> {
        measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        layout(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
    };

}
```